# Does linux perf use kprobe to have a detailed measurement breakdown of each kernel function?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, perf

When we enable perf **call-graph** recording (e.g. perf record -g), the perf tool is able to have a detailed measure breakdown of each small function along the call path, no matter it's kernel or user functions.

I'm wondering how perf is able to achieve this for kernel functions. My guess is that perf leverages `kprobe` to have a callback at each kernel function invocation. Something like this:

- Call foo()

  - Trap to core kprobe layer
  - kprobe callback to perf handler, which setup PMC
- Run foo()
- ret of foo()

  - Trap to core kprobe layer again
  - kprobe callback to perf handler, which read PMC
- Return to caller

Is this correct? Or Linux is actually using some other magic? Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, at each point of interest it stores a backtrace of return addresses. There's no need for kprobe in this. It can be done with dwarf (slower) and with frame pointer (-fno-omit-framepointer, but much faster), and possibly other fancy CPU hardware based ways. At report time, addresses will be resolved to symbols.

Comment: Hi @JohannesSchaub-litb, thank you for your reply. I think you are possibly right on storing the return addresses. But this didn't answer __how__ they got stored. I think in kernel, `kprobe` and `ftrace` are the only two mechanisms that can be used to get the return addresses, using live patch and `-mcount`, respectively. Since `perf record -g` is able to get functions that are not listed in `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/available_filter_functions`, `ftrace` shouldn't be the mechanism to support `perf record -g`. I'm planning to read code this week and will come back with a firm answer.

Comment: while I don't know the answer, I think that it's not got to do with kprobe or ftrace, since they do different things than this. This looks more like it: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/save_stack_trace .

Comment: If you use `perf`, it might use a different mechanism, since `save_stack_trace` looks like a kernel-function, while `perf` of course runs in userspace. I guess `perf` can simply use user-space `libunwind` on the kernel's ELF image. Maybe in the end it's multiple mechanisms, depending in which context the stacktrace is collected (user-space vs kernel-space) and depending on what it is collected (kernel image vs user-space binary). eBPF programs can also collect stack-traces, and they will run in kernel-space.

Comment: We can use `libunwind` to resolve stack trace, but this doesn't explain how collected stats got distributed among small functions.

For example, if we use `perf record -g -e cycles:k ls` and `perf report`. We can see cycles breakdown among the _same_ hierarchy children functions. Just look at the stack trace from NMI handler isn't enough, there must be a way to start/end PMU counting at the entry/exit of each function, so perf is able to measure how each function plays out. And this leads me to kprobe or ftrace. Not sure if I'm make myself clear here. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: My understanding is that if you use `cycles:k`, that requires a sampling frequency using `-F`, and that you only see cycle numbers in the callers if there happened to be samples of them. But if a called function has N samples in function `foo`, and backtraces show that in half the samples, a function `bar` doesn't appear as a caller, I would expect it should give you `50%` presence in the callers for that function. All without kprobe or ftrace. The higher `-F` is, the more accurate is this number.